# How to fix Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer

I tried many ways to fix - clear settings, reinstall Internet Explorer, this link

> http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/problem-with-rasadhlpdll/1535a001-437d-4b4b-aa94-b616b3cae01f

None help me.
I have the following problem: When I start Internet Explorer and try to go to any page Internet Explorer crashes with following information:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BEX
  Application Name: iexplore.exe
  Application Version:  9.0.8112.16421
  Application Timestamp:    4d76255d
  Fault Module Name:    rasadhlp.dll_unloaded
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   2a425e19
  Exception Offset: 13148440
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Data:   00000008
  OS Version:   6.0.6002.2.2.0.274.10
  Locale ID:    1049
  Additional Information 1: 40d4
  Additional Information 2: 4062ad41ec8067256aa4c5e2b56d3c79
  Additional Information 3: 40d4
  Additional Information 4: 4062ad41ec8067256aa4c5e2b56d3c79

Read our privacy statement:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=50163&clcid=0x0409
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: I see that you found the solution to the problem. Generally, providing details as to what sort of problem you're getting can help us provide you with a good solution. For instance, the browser was crashing all the time, or when you go to certain sites. Information like that when coupled with the error log you kindly provided, gives us a better idea what sort of problem you're actually experiencing.

Comment: but I specified it in main post - on any page...

Comment: I'm sorry, you are correct. I did not look hard enough or thoroughly enough to see the description of the error. Either way I'm glad you found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

FIX IT.
It was corrupted (infected) file rasadhlp.dll in folder of IE and all folders of all browsers ( I thought only file in \Windows\system32 is actual). And only IE said that something is wrong!